# Import project module in Cypress

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, integration-testing, cypress

I want to import some constants from my project into my tests (for instance to test `localstorage` operations). While using `import` (or `require`) from my IDE doesn't show errors:

[image]

When running Cypress I get: `Error: Cannot find module`

[image]

The module is in TypeScript (*Config.ts*) despite doesn't use any particular feature.

I didn't modify any of the Command or Support script. But I have in the Cypress folder a *tsconfig.json* so that my Create React App can run without conflict with Jest.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig",
  "include": ["../node_modules/cypress/types", "**/*.ts"]
}
```

I tried to add *../src* or *../src/**/*.ts* in the `include` but nothing seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @eric99 the mismatch of path is simply a sloppy attempt to privacy. Adding ".ts" I get a better error (the path worked): ```/Users/blahblahblah/src/data/Config.ts:1
export const MY_CONSTANT = 'MY_VALUE';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'```

Comment: This plugin [cypress-webpack-preprocessor](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-webpack-preprocessor) allows ts imports to work.

Answer (score 17):

Add [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack), [cypress-webpack-preprocessor](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-webpack-preprocessor) and [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) if they are not already present:

```sh
yarn add --dev webpack @cypress/webpack-preprocessor ts-loader
```

In *cypress/plugins/index.js* just add this to your config:

```js
const wp = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor')

module.exports = (on) => {
  const options = {
    webpackOptions: {
      resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: { transpileOnly: true }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  }
  on('file:preprocessor', wp(options))
}
```

Cypress should now load your TS files.

*More information about a full TS config: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/testing/cypress.html*

Comment: saved my life with error: ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Comment: for cli-plugin-e2e-cypress for Vue3 this is necessary since it doesnt use cypress v4.4.0

Comment: the solution worked for me, because we use Vue, we also needed to add the following options into cypress/plugins/index.js:
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve('src')
        }
      }

Comment: Configuring plugins via `cypress/plugins/index.js` is no longer supported as of Cypress version 10.0.0.

Answer (score 6):

As of April 2020 and cypress v4.4.0 this setup is not necessary anymore, as Cypress now supports typescript ootb.

Basically now you just have to add typescript (if not already present) to your project `npm install typescript --save-dev` and add a `tsconfig.json` into your cypress-folder, with content similiar to this:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Taken from and see 
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html#Set-up-your-dev-environment for more information.